# What were the memorable scenes in "A Storm of Swords" that motivated Benioff to make the adaptation?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Just to be clear, this is not a "make a list for me" question, it is about what motivated Benioff to get on board with the *Game of Thrones*.

In the Wikipedia article for [*Game of Thrones*, season 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_of_Thrones_%28season_3%29), you can read the following:

> According to Benioff, the third season will contain a particularly
>   memorable scene from A Storm of Swords, the prospect of filming which
>   was part of their motivation to adapt the novels for television in the
>   first place.

I've also seen elsewhere that there are in fact two scenes. Does anyone know which scene or scenes they refer to that provided such a major influence in getting the books made into a show? The only thing that springs to mind is (spoiler ASOS)

> The Red Wedding. Or possibly the assault on the Wall by Mance Rayder.

Comment: Voting to close because any "memorable" scenes are going to be found on the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_storm_of_swords) page. That being said, I would say that the scene you listed as well as what occurs at Castle Black are probably the two strongest possibilities.

Comment: Even if they weren't on Wikipedia, this would be a make-a-list question. Definitely needs closing.

Comment: I don't think this is a list question (although the title could be worded better), as it asks about a certain scene (or scenes) that was referenced by Benioff.

Comment: I agree with @SystemDown.  The question could probably use some editing, but it doesn't look like the intent is "give me every memorable scene in the book".

Comment: @Beofett - you're right. I VTCed before reading your comment, but will VTRO if it gets closed. Sorry. +1

Comment: It isn't a list question if the list can only be 1 or 2 items long.

Comment: Well, wow... closed? Really? My question was what Benioff considered memorable scenes, if anyone knew. Not what the memorable scenes of ASOS was. Although I would welcome speculation about the scenic qualities of the scenes in ASOS.

Comment: @TLP Your original question asked "What are the memorable scenes in *A Storm of Swords*?" That is definitely general reference, and while you did make a mention of wanting the scene that motivated Benioff, the wording of the question as well as your own "guess" indicated that all you were looking for was memorable scenes. The edits since have cleared things up a bit, but your original question was not a good one, and was properly closed as general reference. (IMO)

Comment: @nominsim No, the title perhaps should have said `theSE "memorable scenes"` instead. I'll grant you that if you see the title without reading the question, you might think it is a bad question. As for myself, I have a hard time imagining how anyone could have read that question and not understand what I meant.

Comment: In fact, since the question starts off by referring to Benioff mentioning memorable scenes, how is it even possible to infer in that context that all I want is a list of scenes?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The scene Benioff was talking about is almost certainly

> The Red Wedding

It was recently revealed that there is a [casting call](http://www.westeros.org/GoT/News/Entry/Its_a_Nice_Day_For_A/) for cellists "ideally men with medieval or period faces (i.e. long hair and beards)", as well as "LEG ONLY, MALE AMPUTEES" who are "OK and comfortable with filming a scene within the context of a battle where your leg has been injured. Prosthetic makeup will be applied as though your leg has newly been severed."

The Cellists make it almost certainly the aforementioned event, as music was a key part (*The Rains of Castamere*, anyone?).

The scene itself is one of the most heart wrenching and emotionally disturbing in the entire series, and George R.R. Martin himself has stated that the scene is [the most difficult he has ever written](http://www.empireonline.com/interviews/interview.asp?IID=1496).

On a personal note:

> The willingness of Martin to kill off of major characters has become one of the stand-out aspects of his writing, and the shock of realizing what has happened the first time I read it really changed my perspective on the whole series, even more so than the death of Ned Stark.

Regarding the full context of the [interview with Benioff](http://insidetv.ew.com/2012/03/30/game-of-thrones-showrunners-season-2/2/) referenced in the question:

> The Red Wedding seems particularly suited towards an incredibly momentous and dramatic televised scene, largely due to the tension of the wedding leading up to it, and the fact that the combat noises are drowned out by loud music.  I can easily envision bloody fight scenes interspaced with dramatic closeups of musicians furiously playing as loudly as they can, and this ties in almost exactly with the casting call descriptions cited above.

Regarding the second scene mentioned, I can only speculate.  However, in addition to the other scene you mentioned in your question (which does seem a very likely candidate), I think these are just as likely, if not more:

> Daenerys taking command of the army of Unsullied and turning them upon their Astaporian masters, the duel of Oberyn Martel vs. Ser Gregor Clagane, the escape of Tyrion, or possibly even the return of Catelyn Stark.

Comment: My answer only addresses one scene, as the original question does not provide any context for the claim of a second scene being influential in the decision.

Comment: I think it was mentioned in one of the articles that is in wikipedias reference list that there were if fact two scenes. It was also mentioned that this supposedly is a secret, hence my question. I am not sure what that scene you mention has that is so powerful as to inspire Benioff, though. Thoughts on that?

Comment: @TLP Please see my edits as to why the scene is so powerful.

Comment: The battle to music seems convincing. It certainly is a momentous enough event, I just did not quite see it all that visually powerful, but you have probably nailed it here. Might be a season finale.

Comment: This answer is also supported by this [response](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=paOFccJcWbo&t=6m43s) by Benioff at the 2011 San Diego Comic-Con panel.

Comment: @dbb He actually says "If we can get to RW" so that seems to confirm it fully.